# Segmentation fault (コアダンプ ) の原因が分からない

Tags: c

以下のプログラムをコンパイルして、実行したところSegmentation fault(コアダンプ)と表示されてしまいます。

どこか間違っているでしょうか？

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define N 10
#define NUM_SCORE 50

int main ( void ) 
{

    int i,j,n;
    int score[ NUM_SCORE ] = {
        1,  4,  9,  9,  8, 10, 10,  9,  5, 10, 
        2,  9,  6,  4,  0,  7,  3,  5,  6,  6, 
        7,  4,  2,  9,  2,  5,  5,  3,  1,  9, 
        5,  7,  3,  2,  7,  9,  1,  7,  6,  6, 
        5,  8,  2,  5,  3, 10,  6,  2,  2,  5, 
    };

    int histogram[ N+1 ]; /* 点数 i の学生の人数を格納する配列 histogram[i] */

    for( i = 0; i <= N; i++ )
    {   
        histogram[ i ] = 0;
    }
    
    for( j = 0; j <= NUM_SCORE; j++ )
    {
        histogram[ score[ j ] ]++;
    }

    /* 結果の表示 */
    printf("点数の分布は以下の通りです．\n");
    for ( i = 0; i <= N; i++ ) 
    {
        printf(" %2d点: %d\n ", i, histogram[i] );
    }
    n = 0;
    for ( i = 7; i <= N; i++ )
    {
        n = n + histogram[ i ];
    }
    printf( "7点以上の人は%d人います", n );
    
    return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

複合条件ですね。
まずこの行の継続条件`j <= NUM_SCORE`が`=`を含んでいるために配列`score`のサイズをオーバーしているからです。

```
for( j = 0; j <= NUM_SCORE; j++ )
```

こちらが`score`の宣言

```
int score[ NUM_SCORE ] = {
```

このように宣言している場合、有効なインデックス値は`0`～`(NUM_SCORE - 1)`の範囲になります。
そして`score`の範囲外のデータを基に以下の行で更に配列`histogram`の範囲外(ここは最大値+1といった値では無くもっと大きな値)をアクセスしてしまったのでしょう。
そのためSegmentation fault(コアダンプ)になったと考えられます。

```
histogram[ score[ j ] ]++;
```

`for`ループ継続条件の`=`を外して`NUM_SCORE`未満とすれば問題なく動作します。

```
for( j = 0; j < NUM_SCORE; j++ )
```

---

別の`N`を使ったループは、対象配列の`int histogram[ N+1 ];`が`N+1`個の領域で確保されているため、こちらは

```
for ( i = 0; i <= N; i++ )
```

とか

```
for ( i = 7; i <= N; i++ )
```

でループしても問題無い訳です。
(ただし、配列のインデックス値の範囲としては問題無いですが、実際に行うべき処理として問題無いかどうかは別です。今回は大丈夫そうですが、#defineマクロの数値の意味付けは気を付けた方が良いでしょう。)

---

短いプログラムの中で、配列の要素数の宣言の仕方が混在していることも、誤解を生みやすい原因でしょう。

Comment: 教えていただいた通りに修正すると正しく動作しました。for( i = 7; i <= N; i++ )の７を入力された値になるように修正したのですが、また同じエラーが出てしまいました。printfとscanfを追加しただけなので分からなくて困っています。よろしければお願いします。

Comment: 類似の現象ではあっても、新たな事象ですので、追加したソースと共に新しい質問を起こしてください。どのようなソースで問題が出たのか提示されないと答えられませんよ。あるいは@metropolis さん紹介の方法やツールで自分でチェックしてみるのも良いかもしれません。

Answer (score 1):

参考情報として、使用している C コンパイラが gcc の場合、配列の範囲外アクセス(`out of bounds access`)に対して警告(warning)を表示するオプションが用意されています。

**gcc(1)**

> **-Warray-bounds**
> **-Warray-bounds=n**
>  This option is only active when -ftree-vrp is active (default for -O2 and above). It warns about subscripts to arrays that are always out of bounds. This warning is enabled by -Wall.
>  
>  **-Warray-bounds=1**
>   This is the warning level of -Warray-bounds and is enabled by -Wall; higher levels are not, and must be explicitly requested.
>  
>  **-Warray-bounds=2**
>   This warning level also warns about out of bounds access for arrays at the end of a struct and for arrays accessed through pointers. This warning level may give a larger number of false positives and is deactivated by default.

```sh
$ gcc --version
gcc (Ubuntu 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04) 9.3.0

$ gcc -O2 -Warray-bounds -o histogram histogram.c
histogram.c: In function ‘main’:
histogram.c:27:21: warning: iteration 50 invokes undefined behavior [-Waggressive-loop-optimizations]
   27 |     histogram[ score[ j ] ]++;
      |                ~~~~~^~~~~
histogram.c:25:3: note: within this loop
   25 |   for( j = 0; j <= NUM_SCORE; j++ )
      |   ^~~
```

その他に [cppcheck - A tool for static C/C++ code analysis](https://sourceforge.net/p/cppcheck/wiki/Home/) を利用しても同様の結果が得られます。

```sh
$ cppcheck --enable=all histogram.c 
Checking histogram.c ...
histogram.c:27:21: error: Array 'score[50]' accessed at index 50, which is out of bounds. [arrayIndexOutOfBounds]
    histogram[ score[ j ] ]++;
                    ^
```