# 入力ができません。

Tags: c

以下のプログラムを実行したところ、二つの配列を入力したいのですが、二つ目の配列が入力できず、そのままif文が実行されてしまいます。
どこか足りていないのでしょうか？
教えてください。よろしくお願いします。

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define N 128
int main( void )
{
    char str_input[ N ];
    char str_new[ N ];
    
    printf( "Key in a letter>> ");
    str_input[ N ] = getchar();
    printf( "%d\n", strlen( str_input ) );
    
    printf( "Key in a letter>> ");
    str_new[ N ] = getchar();
    
    if ( strcmp( str_input, str_new ) == 0 )
    {
        printf( "文字列 str_input と str_new は一致しています\n" );
    }
    else
    {
        printf( "文字列 str_input と str_new は一致していません\n" );
    }
    
    strcpy( str_input, str_new );
    
    if( strcmp( str_input, str_new ) == 0 )
    {
        printf( "文字列 str_input と str_new は一致しています\n" );
    }
    else
    {
        printf( "文字列 str_input と str_new は一致していません\n" );
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

質問された方のコードは、配列の有効範囲を超えて代入しています。

```
 #define N 128
 int main( void )
 {
     char str_input[ N ];
```

char str_input[ N ];は要素数が128個のchar型の配列を宣言していますが、

```
     str_input[ N ] = getchar();
```

この文ではgetchar()で標準入力から読み込んだ1文字をstr_input[N]つまりstr_input[128]に代入しています。
C言語の配列の添え字は0から始まりますので、129番目の要素に代入していることになります。
これは配列の範囲外に代入しているのでバグです。

str_newも同じ問題があります。

---

```
    if ( strcmp( str_input, str_new ) == 0 )
    {
        printf( "文字列 str_input と str_new は一致しています\n" );
```

このコードをみるとstr_inputとstr_newを文字列比較していますので、str_inputには文字列を入力したいのだと思います。
今のコードは入力した1文字をstr_inputに格納しているだけなので、「文字列」を入力するように変更するか、1文字入力を繰り返す必要があると思います。

Answer (score 0):

繰り返しになりますが、前々回 [Segmentation fault(コアダンプ)の原因が分からない](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/72118/) と前回 [Segmentation fault(コアダンプ)の原因が分かりません](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/72128/) の質問に対する回答で紹介されている [cppcheck](https://sourceforge.net/p/cppcheck/wiki/Home/) でチェックしてみると、これまでの質問と同様の原因(`arrayIndexOutOfBounds`)によるエラーである事が判ります。

```c
$ cppcheck -v --enable=all input_string.c
Checking input_string.c ...
Defines:
Undefines:
Includes:
Platform:Native
input_string.c:11:12: error: Array 'str_input[128]' accessed at index 128, which is out of bounds. [arrayIndexOutOfBounds]
  str_input[ N ] = getchar();
           ^
input_string.c:15:10: error: Array 'str_new[128]' accessed at index 128, which is out of bounds. [arrayIndexOutOfBounds]
  str_new[ N ] = getchar();
         ^
input_string.c:12:3: portability: %d in format string (no. 1) requires 'int' but the argument type is 'size_t {aka unsigned long}'. [invalidPrintfArgType_sint]
  printf( "%d\n", strlen( str_input ) );
  ^
```

最後の `invalidPrintfArgType_sint` ですが、`printf(3)` に説明があります。

**printf(3)**

> **Length modifier**
>    Here, "integer conversion" stands for d, i, o, u, x, or X conversion.
>
> **z**   A following integer conversion corresponds to a size_t or ssize_t argument, or a following n conversion corresponds to a pointer to a size_t argument.

この場合、文字列の長さなので `unsigned int` を指定します(`%zu`)。

```c
  printf("%zu\n", strlen(str_input));
```

その他、入力の読み込みに `getchar()` が使用されていますが、1文字(1 byte)しか読み込みませんので、2文字以上の文字列を読み込みたいのであれば `fgets(3)` などを利用する方が良いかと思います。

**fgetc(3)**

> **NAME**
>    fgetc, fgets, getc, getchar, ungetc - input of characters and strings
>
> **DESCRIPTION**
>    **fgetc()** reads the next character from stream and returns it as an unsigned char cast to an int, or EOF on end of file or error.
>
> **getc()** is equivalent to fgetc() except that it may be implemented as a macro which evaluates stream more than once.
>
> **getchar()** is equivalent to getc(stdin).
>
> **fgets()** reads in at most one less than size characters from stream and stores them into the buffer pointed to by s. Reading stops after an EOF or a newline. **If a newline is read, it is stored into the buffer**. **A terminating null byte('\0') is stored after the last character in the buffer**.